# Is Monoid[String] really a Monoid in scala

Tags: scala, category-theory, monoids

I am currently learning about category theory in scala and the law of associativity says

> (x + y) + z = x + (y + z)

Thats just fine when working with more than two values

```
("Foo" + "Bar") + "Test" == "Foo" + ("Bar" + "Test") // true
```

In that case order doesn't matter. But what if there are only two values. In case for numbers its still working ( commutative ) but when doing the same thing with strings it fails.

```
3+1==1+3 // True
("Foo" + "Bar") == ("Bar" + "Foo") // Not commuative
```

So is it legal to say that associativity requires commudativity to fullfill the monoid law ? And so is a String Monoid valid anyway ?

Comment: The monoid operation doesn't have to be commutative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So is it legal to say that associativity requires commutativity to fulfill the monoid law?

No. A binary operation does not need to be commutative to be associative. The fact that `("Foo" + "Bar") == ("Bar" + "Foo")` is false is irrelevant to the fact that `+` is associative for `String.`

> And so is a String Monoid valid anyway?

Yes, you can have a `Monoid[String]`.

By definition:

> A monoid is a set that is closed under an associative binary operation `+`and has an identity element `I` in `S` such that for all `a` in `S`, I `+ a = a + I = a`.
>
> A monoid must contain at least one element.

Let `+` be the binary operation for a `Monoid[String]`. For any two strings, `a` and `b`, `a + b` is also a `String`, so the binary operation is closed over the type `String`. Without rigorous proof, we also know that it is associative.

i.e. for all strings `a`, `b`, and `c`:

```
(a + b) + c == a + (b + c)
```

We also have an identity element `""` (the empty string), because for any string `a`, `a + "" == a` and `"" + a == a`.

A monoid whose binary operation is also a commutative is called a *commutative monoid*. And you clearly cannot have a commutative monoid for `String` using the `+` operation.

Comment: One more question. What is this identity element really used for ?

Comment: For instance, to avoid special cases. Consider concatenating a list of strings. You keep appending consecutive strings to an accumulator string. The simplest implementation starts with the accumulator being an empty string. Compare this with initializing the accumulator using the first string. What if there is no first string (the list is empty)?

Another example is terminating recursion. If I'm done, return an empty string (or an identity for a general monoid).